# Are there any algorithms that run in (2 ↑ ↑ n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I’m wondering whether there are any algorithms that use so much time that they must be represented using [Knuth up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Required: Use more than one up-arrow for time complexity.

Bonus points:

- Have the algorithm be useful.
- Have the algorithm be useful and optimized

Sister question on CS: (recommendation from @Amy)
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/94184/are-there-any-algorithms-that-run-in-2-↑-↑-n

Comment: Windows 95 on a 386?

Comment: @Owl I hope you’re joking

Comment: But yes, some types of neural networks i.e. that brute force binary into logic gates will take this long.

Comment: Interesting... I’ll have to learn that eventually

Comment: I have only ever seen Big O specified as a polynomial with exponents, logs and multiplication.  I can't say I've ever seen Big O specified with an exponent that is itself exponentiated.  I'm sure you could devise such an algorithm, but it wouldnt be useful for anything.

Comment: @Amy which is exactly why I am asking. I’ve only seen them with exponents, I ask this out of curiosity

Comment: Well I'm up-voting because I think it's an interesting question which I expect hasn't been asked before.  I don't think you'll get an answer involving a named algorithm (a heavily contrived and useless algorithm could be devised), but its interesting nonetheless.  I *think* the closest you'll come to this is the [time complexity of a General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).  Note the log of a log, which is then exponentiated.

Comment: The cop-out answer without the bonus points is that given _any_ computable function, you can easily make an algorithm whose runtime is at bounded below by that function: the algorithm simply computes the value of the function and then proceeds to output every natural number less than the result.

Comment: Yeah, an answer can be devised.  I think the OP is looking for a *named* algorithm.  A loop of *n* elements is O(n).  A loop of *n* elements with an inner loop of *n* elements is O(n * n), or O(n^2).  If you had *n* inner loops of *n* items in each loop, that might give you the desired level of exponentiation.  Maybe.  :-/

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder You might consider asking this instead on [cs.se], which is focused a little more on theory.

Comment: You might be interested in the disjoint set algorithms, some of which take `O(a(n))` time, where `a(n)` is the inverse Ackerman function. The Ackerman function grows faster(?) than up arrow notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Answer (score 0):

Answering this to get this question off the unanswered queue.

As mentioned in the related question linked, a simple automaton-based algorithm for answering first-order queries in Presburger arithmetic (and some extensions) has worst-case running time about 2↑↑n, where n is the number of quantifier alternations in the query. It has both been implemented and provides useful results. Find more about it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06017)